Facebook App Links on iOS lost parameters in al:ios:url
I am trying to make app link work via facebook browser on iOS.
I have this header on web page:
<meta property="al:ios:url" content="applink://parameter" />

The page is deployed onto, let's say, https://www.foo.bar/test
When I open this link via fb app browser (e.g from comments section), my app opens as expected, but deeplink does not contain parameter
However if I open link https://www.foo.bar/test.html, app correctly receieves full deeplink.
Any tips how to tackle the problem? It doesn't make any sense, the web page is the same, only link has an extension.

Seems that you need to go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/, enter your URL and scrape the URL, then it works.
